# Use a specific column for ordering table

Tags: sql, database, sorting, sql-order-by, columnsorting

I have a table for categories on my posts database, I wanna make a specific order for them, so when I'm trying to insert a new record, It's not necessary to be stored at the end of table.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "stored at the end" ? Is it the last column in your insert statement or are you talking about the order of the rows when you extract the data?

Comment: You don't even know where the row is stored, the dbms decides. Use ORDER BY to select the data in the wanted order.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about the order of retrieved data, I just wanna order the retrieved data by a specific column for ordering.

Without any need to update the order value when inserting a new row.

Comment: Assume we have a table that contains a user name and the order of row,
Name      |     Order
John        |     1
Nicole      |     2


But the problem here is when I wanna insert a new row between the first and the second one.

Comment: The bigger challenge is how to solve this problem without any need for data updating.

Comment: Don't bother. Just INSERT data, and specify ORDER BY when you do SELECT. That's what databases are meant for.

Comment: "But the problem here is when I wanna insert a new row between the first and the second one"  that will require an update, or an insert trigger, anyway you will have to update the data in your table. One way to prevent (for a time only) this kind of issue is having your order in 10s instead of 1s.
Name | Order John | 1 Nicole | 2 becomes Name | Order John | 10 Nicole | 20 now if you want to insert something in between you can but it will only work for a short time if you have a lot of inserts that happen between to existing Orders

Comment: You can reload all the table once and multiply order column by 10 or 100. or alternatively alter column, change type to float and use fractional numbers

Answer (score 0):

The order of rows and columns is immaterial to the DBMS. Rows are not stored at the end and select without `order by` does not guarantee the order of rows. Even if data can be stored ordered in the files, due to parallel execution, result is not ordered.

If you want to get ordered dataset, use `ORDER BY` in your query.

Comment: It's not my issue absolutely, 
I just wanna get data in a specific order

Comment: Ok, I can use order by, but for what?
I have a column for order that contains values from 1 to n, 
each row has an order number, What will happen if I try to make the last row at the top of the data?

This is my issue.

Comment: @MhdMazenAl-Samman what does it mean: "if I try to make that last column at the top of the data" please explain how it should be ordered

Comment: @MhdMazenAl-Samman select column1, ...columnN from tablename ORDER BY column, column - this is how to get ordered data. How it is stored does not matter, what matters is how you ordered when selected

Answer (score 0):

If you want ot order the extracted data then you should use the order by clause

```
SELECT Name, Order
FROM MyTalbe
WHERE ...
ORDER BY Order
```

Col1 being your column with the number from 1 to N